# SQL Server unique constraint issue on unicode characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, unique-constraint

I have my table definition as follows:

```
create table [Language](
Id int primary key identity,
Code varchar(11) not null unique,
NativeName nvarchar(50) not null unique
)
```

And then, I have a long list of statements that insert into that table. The problem is that some of the insert statements conflict on my `NativeName` column's unique constraint. The weird thing is that the content is not unique at all. For example, if I only insert the following with the table empty:

```
insert into Language (Code, NativeName) values('am', N'አማርኛ');
insert into Language (Code, NativeName) values('dv', N'ދިވެހިބަސް‏');
```

I get for the second insert.

```
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__Language__EB1957A5F98D1F9C'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Language'. The duplicate key value is (ދިވެހިބަސް‏).
```

Does anyone know why unicode characters are causing these issues?

Comment: Sounds like a collation issue. See [Working with Collations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187582(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try declaring the NativeName column with a more specific (binary) collation.

eg:

```
 NativeName nvarchar(50) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN not null unique
```

Comment: I knew this query needed some sort of collation fix but how did you figure it out which collation would do the job as far as i can see these two different languages in this query the OP is trying to insert. Could you please give some explanation Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @MuhammedAli The key is that it is a binary collation - I picked this one as it is a generic, rather than a linguistic collation, but in all likelihood any of the binary collations would work.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. To be honest I'm completely ignorant on what is going on. I think I have to do some research on this whole collation thing.

Comment: Please help me to understand your answer: does it *reproduce* the issue (and thus answer the question *why..?*) or *fix* it?

Comment: @AndriyM This will fix it.